# How to work with template styles in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, templates

I've recently been doing MOS Word 2013 Expert part two certification and there were a few tasks about template styles which I couldn't solve.

1. "Attach to template style" with specified "file source". Unfortunately I don't even know what is meant by this task. Probably something like "copy styles from a template file and apply them to current document". Am I right? How can I accomplish this?
2. "Apply the copied style to all page headers". I've had some style copied from another file but I don't know how could I apply it to all page headers at once (not manually select all headers and click that style). What's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. is answered by [Quickly Formatting Multiple Documents](http://word.tips.net/T001516_Quickly_Formatting_Multiple_Documents.html)

Comment: You're welcome. You might find the answer to 2. on that site as well. (I didn't look). It has a lot of good tips.